External hard disk suddenly slow, then "normal" again; defective?
3 months ago, I bought a Seagate 4TB 2.5" hard disk (ST4000LM024) and used it for a few days, without any problems.
Lately I got it again to backup a lot of files, and it was really slow. I tried all kinds of operations, benchmarking, unplugging/replugging, S.M.A.R.T., changing the USB case, etc. It was unusable, at 2 MB/s even for sequential access:

Id didn't suffer any damage and has been used very little.
I was going to return it, but I needed to safely remove my data, so I connected to another laptop (Windows), reformatted, and started writing 1 MB files (with zeroes) into it. It was still very slow, writing about 1-2 files per second (simply formatting the partition to NTFS took several minutes). I left the laptop, which went to sleep after 5 minutes, and when I came back, I turned it on again, and resumed the operation.
This time, the drive "magically" restarted with "normal" speeds:

Note that I had already changed computers, changed the USB case, powered off/on again several times, etc. I really have no idea why this time it "resurrected". I wrote over 1 TB of data to it, to check it was not some caching issue, and the speed was consistently high all the time.
I still don't know if I should return the drive as possibly defective, or what caused it. Overheating? Some weird software glitch? Self-protecting mode? Exotic USB malfunction? I could find no documentation about such behavior. The fact that it happened both on Linux and Windows, on 2 different laptops, with different USB cases, makes me think it is something internal to the HDD itself. But then, shouldn't it be documented somewhere?
This question suggests it might be due to SMR; but I still fail to understand how SMR could "remain active" after stopping and restarting the drive. And I thought that writing to the entire disk would somehow show it again; maybe I should write a different pattern other than zeroes?
This other question seems to have a very similar issue to mine, but no explanation was ever found. Their solution was simply to "quick format it using Windows". But I need an ext partition, so I cannot do that...
Ok, I managed to put it back again in the "sh*tty" state:

Reformatted with an ext4 partition (about 500GB) + an NTFS partition (3.5 TB) from Linux ;
Wrote 64k 1M files to the ext4 partition, no issues;
Started writing 64k 1M files to the NTFS partition, it became "useless" after a few thousand files. After doing some more operations, it seems to "resume", then comes back to the "slow" state, in a somewhat predictable manner.

All symptoms point to SMR indeed, so I guess the only reasonable choice is to return the HDD and try something else.

'I still fail to understand how SMR could "remain active" after stopping and restarting the drive' – How else could rewriting reliably work in case of stopping and restarting the drive during the operation? The internal controller of the HDD is a tiny computer with firmware; and the main point of HDD is to be non-volatile memory. This means the HDD is able to journal the state of the operation and to resume later. I'm not saying this is what happened in your case; I'm only saying that resuming maintenance after power cycling is totally possible.

So, the behavior might have been caused by the fact that, even after turning the drive off and on again, the "cache" was still updating entries? This opaqueness of the internal behavior with a clearly visible side-effect (abysmal performance) is completely user-hostile! I'm still trying to convince myself it's "just" the SMR causing all of this, given how terrible it behaves. In any case, thanks for the comment, it does make sense.
